# How do I make git post-receive emails be sent from the commit author?

Tags: git, email, hook, post-commit

I'm using the post-receive-email script included with git.  (Source is [here](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email).)  It works just fine, but I want each email to be sent from the author of the commits pushed.  How do I do it?

My post-receive file currently looks like this, and I want to customize the from-email-address.

```
#!/bin/sh

export USER_EMAIL=from-email-address@blah.com
$(dirname $0)/post-receive-email
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use `git log` to pull out the email address.**

For example, in `post-receive`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Use the email address of the author of the last commit.
export USER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --format=format:%ae HEAD)
$(dirname $0)/post-receive-email
```

You could also map the email addresses, if for example, people are using their gmail or personal domain addresses, but you would like to map them to a single domain.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Use the mapped email address (specified in .mailmap) of the author of the last commit.
export USER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --format=format:%aE HEAD)
$(dirname $0)/post-receive-email
```

You can read more about `.mailmap` [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html).

Comment: and it doesn't work for branches. If someone commits in a branch, the auther will always be the last one from the master.

Comment: You're right, I do have the branch problem you mention. Do you know how to fix it? It's never bothered me enough to look into it.

Comment: Instead of getting the last log entry, you could use: git log GIT_COMMIT_HASH --pretty=format:%ae | head -1

Comment: You may use `git log -all` instead of `git log HEAD` to make it work for all branches too (see my longer response)

Answer (score 1):

You can try another hook system like http://github.com/jtek/git-hook-update-notify-email

Answer (score 1):

The following may be better, to correctly handle commits made on
branches (used on a Debian system) :

```
#! /bin/sh
git config hooks.envelopesender $(git log -all -1 --pretty=format:%ae)
. /usr/share/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email
```

The `git log --all` instead of `git log HEAD` will use the latest
commit on all branches, supposedly the right one to notify about.

The `git config hooks.envelopesender` may be replaced by another of
the variants mentioned above. YMMV.